# How to include null/undefined values when using lodash filter

Tags: javascript, filter, lodash

I would like to filter on a particular object property. If that property is false OR undefined/null, I want it included. In the example below, I am summing by the deliciousRating as long as isBruised is not true. However, I can't figure out how to include the undefined/null value.

```
var apples = [
    {isBruised: true, deliciousRating: 1},
    {isBruised: false, deliciousRating: 10},
    {deliciousRating: 9}
];

_.sumBy(_.filter(apples, ['isBruised', false]), 'deliciousRating');
```

I would like this to return 19, but currently it is only getting the deliciousRating from apples[1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`_.reject()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reject) instead of `_.filter()`. The `_.reject()` method is...

> The opposite of _.filter; this method returns the elements of
>   collection that predicate does not return truthy for.

```js
var apples = [
    {isBruised: true, deliciousRating: 1},
    {isBruised: false, deliciousRating: 10},
    {deliciousRating: 9}
];

var result = _.sumBy(_.reject(apples, 'isBruised'), 'deliciousRating');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And in vanilla JS, you can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum just the items that are not bruised:

```js
var apples = [
    {isBruised: true, deliciousRating: 1},
    {isBruised: false, deliciousRating: 10},
    {deliciousRating: 9}
];

var result = apples.reduce(function(s, o) {
  return o.isBruised ? s : s + o.deliciousRating;
}, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use native filter function `.filter((v) => !v.isBruised)`. Will include `deliciousRating` key either if `isBruised` is `null`, `undefined`, `false` or if doesn't exist.

```js
const apples = [
    {isBruised: true, deliciousRating: 1},
    {isBruised: false, deliciousRating: 10},
    {deliciousRating: 9}
];

const r = _.sumBy(apples.filter((v) => !v.isBruised), 'deliciousRating');

console.log(r);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```